# Database transactions between multiple camel routes

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

How transactions works in Camel routes with Spring DSL and one of the route throws Exception?

If routeB throws an exception, how exception will be propagated back to routeA.

If exception is thrown in routeB, I could see `transactionalErrorHandler` is handling the exception and rolling back the transaction.

Setting the `errorHandlerRef="noErrorHandler"` on routeB does not help.

How can we do this?

My Camel routes definition:

```
<route id="routeA">
  <from uri="direct-vm:endpointA" />
  <transacted />
  <to uri="direct-vm:endPointB" />
  <bean ref="beanA" method="save" />
  <onException>
    <exception>java.lang.Exception>
    <handled><constant>true</constant></handled>
    <bean ref="beanA" method="handleError" />
    <rollback markRollbackOnly="true" />
  </onException>
</route>

<route id="routeB">
  <from uri="direct-vm:endPointB" />
  <throwException ref="ex"/>
</route>
```

Answer (score 1):

In camel the `transacted` command is simply a wrapper for the Spring `TransactionTemplate`, in that it will enlist the route in a transaction supplied by the `PlatformTransactionManager`. The only configuration option you get on the `org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy` is the propagation behaviour, so handling rollbacks etc must be done within the transacted route.

In this case you should catch the exception from route B, if it gets to the error handler then it is too late.

```
<route id="routeA">
    <from uri="direct-vm:endpointA" />
    <transacted/>
    <doTry>
        <to uri="direct-vm:endPointB" />
        <doCatch>
           <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
           <bean ref="beanA" method="handleFail"/>
        </doCatch>
        <doFinally>
           <bean ref="beanA" method="save" />
        </doFinally>
    </doTry>
</route>

<route id="routeB">
    <from uri="direct-vm:endPointB" />
    <throwException ref="ex"/>
</route>
```

Comment: I might not be clear with my question. Both the routes should participate in transaction and when routeB throws exception, routeA onException should handle exception instead of transactionalErrorHandler.